# Page not found 404 en peticion GET con parametro en LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, error404

estoy teniendo un problema ya por mucho tiempo. Sucede que basicamente lo que estoy intentado hacer es pasar un parámetro a una vista con Laravel de la forma más básica posible, pero lo que obtengo es un

> Page Not Found Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/locacion/empleado/{$id}', 'EmpleadosAdmin@EmpleadoLocacion')->name('empleado.locacion');
```

Es un proyecto al que estoy mentiendo mano, asi que de todas maneras dejo el archivo web.php completo

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('/cargaempleado', 'EmpleadosAdmin');
Route::get('/copyproduct/{id}', 'EmpleadosAdmin@CopyProduct')->name('copyproduct');
Route::get('/editprecio/{id}', 'EmpleadosAdmin@EditPrecio')->name('editprecio');

//Nueva Configuracion de Empleado para cargos y demas rutinas
Route::post('creohistoricocargo','EmpleadosAdmin@CreoHistoricoCargo')->name('historicocargo.index');
Route::post('editarcargohistorico','EmpleadosAdmin@EditoHistoricoCargo')- 
>name('editohistoricocargo.index');

//agregar una imagen 
Route::post('/cargarimagen', 'EmpleadosAdmin@CargaImagen')->name('fotouser');
Route::post('/cargarimagencreate', 'EmpleadosAdmin@CargaImagenCreate')->name('fotouser-create');

//Creo Edito contratos
Route::post('creocontratoempleado', 'EmpleadosAdmin@CreoContratoEmpleado')- 
>name('contratoupdate.index');
Route::post('editcontratoempleado', 'EmpleadosAdmin@UpdateContratoEmpleado')- 
>name('contratoupdate.index');

//Pestaña familia de Empleados
Route::post('agregarFamiliar/','EmpleadosAdmin@nuevofamiliar')- 
>name('nuevo.familiar.empleado.admin');

//Empleado actualizacion del 14 09 2019 agregando carga familiar

Route::get('/pesEmpleado', 'EmpleadosAdmin@pestaEmple');
Route::post('agregarFamiliar/','EmpleadosAdmin@nuevofamiliar')->name('nuevo.familiar');
Route::post('eliminarfamiliar','EmpleadosAdmin@eliminarFamiliar')->name('eliminar.familiar');
Route::post('agregarTelefono/','EmpleadosAdmin@nuevoTelefono')->name('nuevo.telefono');
Route::post('eliminartelefono','EmpleadosAdmin@eliminarTelefono')->name('eliminar.telefono');
Route::post('empleado/fetchprovincia', 'EmpleadosAdmin@fetchProvincia')- 
>name('dynamicdependentprovincia.fetch');
Route::post('empleado/fetchdistrito', 'EmpleadosAdmin@fetchDistrito')- 
>name('dynamicdependentdistrito.fetch');
Route::post('agregarDireccion/','EmpleadosAdmin@nuevaDireccion')->name('nuevo.direccion');

//Rutas de empleados para reporte de empleados
Route::get('reportesempleados','EmpleadosAdmin@reportesporid')->name('reporteempleados');
Route::post('cumpleaños/fetch', 'EmpleadosAdmin@fetchCumpleanios')->name('cumpleanios.fetch');
Route::post('graficos/fetch', 'EmpleadosAdmin@fetchGraficoEmpresa')->name('graficos.fetch');

//reportes de empleados 
Route::post('detallerotacion', 'EmpleadosAdmin@RotacionReporte')->name('reporteempleado.rotacion');

//ruta 12 01 2020
Route::post('/organigramagrafico','EmpleadosAdmin@OrganigramaGrafico')->name('reporte.organigrama');




Route::get('/marcaciones', 'EmpleadosAdmin@Marcaciones')->name('marcaciones');
Route::post('/verificarLocacion', 'EmpleadosAdmin@verificarLocacion');
Route::post('/crearmarcacion', 'EmpleadosAdmin@crearMarcacion');
Route::get('/locaciones','EmpleadosAdmin@Locaciones')->name('locaciones');



Route::get('/locacion/empleado/{$id}', 'EmpleadosAdmin@EmpleadoLocacion')->name('empleado.locacion');
```

Después está el controlador, unicamente colocaré está funcion, en la funcion solo estoy usando un **echo** pero ya he intentado devolver una vista con el parametro pero el resultado es el mismo.

```
public function EmpleadoLocacion($id){
    echo $id;
}
```

Y por ultimo esta es la forma en la que estoy llamando a la ruta

```
@foreach ($locaciones as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item->colaborador }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->contrato }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->local }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('empleado.locacion', $item->id_rh_contrato) }} "><i class="fa 
fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

Porfavor ayudenme a resolver este problema

Comment: Puedes incluir el código de esto: /locacion/empleado/. Seguro está creada esa ruta en el View?

Comment: No entiendo, que significa que termine cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quita el signo `$` en el parámetro:

```
'/locacion/empleado/{$id}'
```

Quedaría en:

```
Route::get('/locacion/empleado/{id}', 'EmpleadosAdmin@EmpleadoLocacion')->name('empleado.locacion');
```